# How to send an object from one activity to another activity by using putExtra()?

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, geopoints

I tried to do it with the parcalebe method but i cant figure out how to use it with a geopoint. This is the object im trying to send. Any help would be appriciated.

```
public class Station implements Parcelable {
    private String description;
    private String linenumber;
    private GeoPoint location;
    private String name;


    public Station(Parcel in) {
        this.description = in.readString();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.linenumber = in.readString();
        this.location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(this.description);
        parcel.writeString(this.name);
        parcel.writeString(this.linenumber);
        parcel.writeDoubleArray(new double[]{this.location.getLatitude(), this.location.getLongitude()});
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Station createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Station(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Station[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Station[i];
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: Thanks but i already tried this method but it doesnt explain how to use with a geopoint.

Comment: Check this https://www.sitepoint.com/transfer-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable/